# Can I shorten this equation?

Tags: vba, excel

VBA newbie here...

I have two lines of code:

```
Application.Goto ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Macros").Range("F1")
Range("F1").FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTA(DBPaste!R[1]C[-5]:R[1000]C[-5])"
```

Can I shorten this?

I tried:

```
Application.Goto ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Macros").Range("F1").FormulaR1C1 = "COUNTA(DBPaste!R[1]C[-5]:R[1000]C[-5])"
```

Thinking that might be it, but it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Just `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Macros").Range("F1").FormulaR1C1 = "COUNTA(DBPaste!R[1]C[-5]:R[1000]C[-5])"`

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm glad it was that easy! Why don't I need the application.goto part though?

Comment: Because you don't have to "go" to (nor "select", nor "activate") a range to apply a method to it. In this case, simply apply the Formula method to the range.

Comment: Makes sense. The new issue that I now get is a type mismatch on the second line below this when running the code.  
    Dim CellNumber As Long
    CellNumber = Cells(1, "F").Value

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of an answer. As explained by @andy “you don't have to "go" to (nor "select", nor "activate") a range to apply a method to it. In this case, simply apply the Formula method to the range” hence, as given by Tim Williams:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Macros").Range("F1").FormulaR1C1 = "COUNTA(DBPaste!R[1]C[-5]:R[1000]C[-5])"
```